# how to extract data inside the list of maps and convert it into maps in dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, set

How can extract data inside the list of maps and convert it into maps in the dart.
**Like I have a List of maps** ================================================================================================================================================================================================

```
[
  {"business_id":"2",
   "business_title":"Spotify",
   "business_phone":"(055) 3733783",
   "business_email":"Usamashafiq309@gmail.com",
   "business_website":"www.spotify.com",
   "business_address":"Spotify AB, Regeringsgatans bro, Stockholm, Sweden",
   "business_address_longitude":"18.0680873",
   "business_address_latitude":"59.33096949999999",
   "business_image":"5f84c7a4bbbd0121020201602537380.png",
   "business_created_at":"2020-10-20 15:40:17",
   "business_category_id":"2",
   "cat_id":"2",
   "cat_title":"Gym",
   "cat_image":"280920201601308237.png"}
    ,{"business_id":"2",
   "business_title":"Spotify",
   "business_phone":"(055) 3733783",
   "business_email":"Usamashafiq309@gmail.com",
   "business_website":"www.spotify.com",
   "business_address":"Spotify AB, Regeringsgatans bro, Stockholm, Sweden",
   "business_address_longitude":"18.0680873",
   "business_address_latitude":"59.33096949999999",
   "business_image":"5f84c7a4bbbd0121020201602537380.png",
   "business_created_at":"2020-10-20 15:40:17",
   "business_category_id":"2",
   "cat_id":"2",
   "cat_title":"Gym",
   "cat_image":"280920201601308237.png"}
 ]
```

**and convert it like this**

```
[ {"business_id":"2",
   "business_title":"Spotify",},
 {"business_id": "1",
            "business_title": "Pizza Hut",},

]
```

Comment: This is something that can be easily achieved with a simple research online. If it still doesn't work, then you need to add what you tried vs what you observed. Check [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks next time i will be careful. @JoyTerence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map` function to apply a function to each element of a list. Then you can create a submap with your map.

Here is a quick exemple:

```
void main() async {
  List l = [
    {
      "business_id": "2",
      "business_title": "Spotify",
      "business_phone": "(055) 3733783",
    },
    {
      "business_id": "1",
      "business_title": "Pizza Hut",
      "business_phone": "(055) 9999999",
    }
  ];

  print(extractMap(l));
}

List extractMap(List l) {
  return l
      .map((element) => Map.fromEntries([
            MapEntry('business_id', element['business_id']),
            MapEntry('business_title', element['business_title']),
          ]))
      .toList();
}
```